# Connection issue with API when using JSON data only in Postman

Tags: json, node.js, postman

I'm trying to setup a simple login API using node.js/restify. The code below shows a simple route, with nothing but a console.log() statement within it, as I'm just trying to prove I can gain a connection.

```
var restify = require('restify');

var user = require('./user');
var reference = require('./reference');

var fs = require('fs');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var _= require('lodash');

const server = restify.createServer();

server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));

server.use(restify.plugins.fullResponse())
server.use(restify.plugins.bodyParser());
server.use(restify.plugins.queryParser())           server.use(restify.plugins.authorizationParser())

var port = 8080;

server.post('/user/login', (req, res) => {

    console.log("---LOGIN ATTEMPT---");


  res.status(200);
  res.end();

});
```

Using Postman for testing, I expect to get a statement back in the console, stating "LOGIN ATTEMPT".

Postman freezes with the 'Loading' text and stays like that until it crashes saying  'There was an error connecting to localhost:8080/user/login'. This only occurs when sending JSON data and not when sending form-data, which is where my confusion is occurring. It is acting as if an infinite loop is occurring with JSON data but can not trace where it is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you are not sending any data back to requesting browser(in this case postman) try returning some response as body

for example use `res.send('success')`

Comment: I added `res.send('success');` above `res.status(200);` but the same thing still occurs. The terminal does not output anything, no error, not even outputting the "login attempt".

Comment: that was just for example as typical express request maybe in restify it can be different
postman hangs that means it is waiting for some data back from server but it's not getting anything back.

Comment: Do you know why form-data would give a normal response acting normally, but only when using JSON it occurs?

Comment: i am not getting your question properly but because using body parser maybe you wont be able to send json post request

Comment: You were right, I have been assuming body parser has been aiding me. Having removed it, it appears to work fine. Thank you!

Comment: please mark answer correct if it resolves your issue. :)